# How to prevent INNER JOIN from returning multiple matches? 

Tags: sql-server-2008, inner-join

Every row in my table on the left should have only one match in the table on the right (right table is the master table with all rows in it; left table contains only a subset of these rows). The timestamps of the rows in each table do not match exactly, but they are usually within 1 second of each other. Therefore, when I join the tables, I have to use:

```
FROM left_table INNER JOIN right_table
ON left_table.timestamp BETWEEN right_table.timestamp - .00015 AND right_table.timestamp + .00015
--This is approximately a 2 second wide range since this is a DATETIME field
AND left_table.name = right_table.name
AND ........
```

Except for the timestamp, every other criteria matches exactly. Is there a way around this?

Most of the time, this is good enough to return only 1 row, but sometimes when there are two identical rows within a second of each other, they will both be returned.

Comment: You could try distinct, or TOP 1.

Comment: In your where clause, did you mean
ON left_table.timestamp BETWEEN right_table.timestamp - .00015 AND right_table.timestamp + .00015

Comment: I guess that is what I'll do.  I just re-evaluated the problem, and I think it's okay if it returns multiple results as long as I use "DISTINCT".  The timespan is so narrow that this works for the criteria that I need from the join.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thank you for catching the error, David!

Comment: PS try to avoid DISTINCT and use GROUP BY

Answer (score 2):

This should be more accurate. The only way to get dupes now is if they both have the same time difference:

```
FROM left_table 
INNER JOIN 
  (
     SELECT l.name, min(abs(r.timestamp - l.timestamp)) as offset
     FROM left_table l
     INNER JOIN right_table ON r on r.name=l.name
     GROUP BY l.name
  ) lrmap ON left_table.name = lrmap.name
INNER JOIN right_table
ON left_table.name = right_table.name
    AND abs(left_table.timestamp-right_table.timestamp) = lrmap.offset
```

I won't vouch for performance, though, because the subtractions are slow and placing them inside the abs() function kills any chance of using indexes on those columns. If I had more time to spend I might be able to put something together that would be more index-friendly... but maybe not, because this looks like weak table design to me, and the real fix will be to add a column that more directly links the records.

Comment: I appreciate the effort.  I'm going to look into this some more, but I think DISTINCT might serve my needs for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need precision down to the second, you could truncate off the rest in your select.

Answer (score 0):

A `where exists()` clause is a good way to prevent Cartesian products

```
FROM left_table lt
where exists(
    select 1 from right_table
    where lt.[timestamp] BETWEEN [timestamp] - .00015 AND [timestamp] + .00015
    and lt.name=name
    AND ........
)
AND ........
```